# Rails with ActionMailer and complex activerecord (joins, where, and)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, actionmailer

I would like to send an email when a project is registered (with a category and a eligible audience) to each user who has created an alert (with the same category and same eligible audience).

**MODEL**

```
class Project
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :fondation
  has_many :project_eligibles
  has_many :eligibles, through: :project_eligibles
end

class Category
  has_many :projects
  has_many :alerts
end

class ProjectEligible
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :eligible
end

class Alert
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :eligible
end
```

**MAILER**

```
class ProjectMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def newproject(project)
    @project = project
      mail(
        to:       mails = User.joins(:alerts).where(alerts: {category_id: project.category_id}).collect(&:email).join(","),
        subject:  "New project for you !"
      )
  end

end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      ProjectMailer.newproject(@project).deliver_now
      redirect_to projects_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

it works with the category but I can't do it with the eligible audience (many_to_many association) :

```
  def newproject(project)
    @project = project
      mail(
        to:       mails = User.joins(:alerts).where(alerts: {eligible_id: project.project_eligibles.where(:eligible_ids)}).collect(&:email).join(","),
        subject:  "New project for you !"
      )
  end

end
```

And more difficult, I don't know how to do it with the 2 conditions ??
Does anyone have an idea to test?

A thousand thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `ProjectMailer`

```
project_elegibles = ProjectEligible.whare("project_id =?", @project.id).pluck(:eligible_id)

User.includes(:alerts).where("alerts.category_id =? and alerts.eligible_id IN (?)", @project.category_id, project_elegibles).pluck(:email)
```

Understand steps that i have used to deal with many-to-many relationship. I can't test this in my machine as I don't have the code. But this will helpful to fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I think that's almost it. But right now I can't complete your solution.
I got this, i tested with a new project, i have on the terminal NULL for alerts.eligible_id : `SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "alerts" ON "alerts"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (alerts.category_id =1 AND alerts.eligible_id IN (NULL))`.

Comment: `project_elegibles` could be `nil` for your case. Make sure you have project eligibles for the @project

Comment: Hi, yes i have project eligibles for the @project. But i always have `NULL`. I don't know why ?

Comment: Do you have eligible_ids for each project items? Try this in console first `ProjectEligible.whare("project_id =?", @project.id)` and check thy have `eligible_id`s `.pluck(:eligible_id)` returns an array of eligible ids.

Comment: Yes i have a array with eligible_ids for all project items.

Comment: What if you try debugging each lines in ProjectMailer.
1. Try `puts @project.inspect` `puts project_elegibles.inspect` `puts [result for second query]`for the same @project instance before calling to mail function.

Comment: if i do this: `Project.create!(title: " test title", description: " sample description", expiration: "2018-11-11", category_id: 1 , fondation_id: 1, project_eligible_ids: [1,2])' .  And 'puts @project.project_eligibles.inspect` . I have `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProjectEligible id: 1, project_id: 443, eligible_id: 1, created_at: "2018-03-15 10:53:46", updated_at: "2018-11-12 15:25:17">, #<ProjectEligible id: 2, project_id: 443, eligible_id: 2, created_at: "2018-03-15 10:53:46", updated_at: "2018-11-12 15:25:17">]>`

Comment: But if i inspect `ProjectEligible.where("project_id =?", @project.id).pluck(:eligible_id)` I have `[]`. It's empty. Do you think i have problems withmy models ?

Comment: In the example I just posted: ids are weird for `EligibleProject`. I just created one for a project and I did a lot of others before to test it but I have an id of 1 with  `created_at: "2018-03-15 10:53:46"` and `updated_at: "2018-11-12 15:25:17"`. Strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `project  = @project`

```
 mails = User.joins(:alerts).where("alerts.eligible_id IN (?) AND alerts.category_id = ?", project.project_eligibles.pluck(:eligible_id), project.category_id).pluck(:"users.email")
```

Possibly you should use `left_outer_join`

For rails 5.x.x

```
mails = User.left_outer_joins(:alerts).where("alerts.eligible_id IN (?) AND alerts.category_id = ?", project.project_eligibles.pluck(:eligible_id), project.category_id).pluck(:"users.email")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have `NULL` for `alerts.eligible_id` . And I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @WhoQui May be you have just setup project and it has no data to test. just add some data so that  you won't get `NULL` for `alerts.eligible_id`

Comment: i have datas and eligible_ids for all project items.